# Automate installation of .Net Core Hosting Bundle with Octopus

Tags: .net, octopus-deploy

I need to automate the install of .Net Core Hosting Bundle using Octopus deploy.  Does anyone have any best practices?
My currently plan is to push the offline executable to the server and install with powershell.  This seems like such a common operation. I would think it would be documented somewhere but I can't find anything.

Is there a better way?  Does Ocotpus already have a package for this that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

On our setup, we use the [Chocolatey package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-windowshosting) for dotnetcore-windowshosting. We have a step template defined that will use the tentacle to copy the package locally, then install it. We use this method so that it can be used with servers in our DMZ, who are blocked from directly accessing chocolatey.org.

Just manually create a new Release each time the choco package is updated, then deploy it by schedule.

See [this blog entry](https://octopus.com/docs/runbooks/runbook-examples/routine/installing-software-chocolatey) for some more information on using choco with octo. After the weekend I may update this Answer with details from work.